# How to calculate advertising copy wearout using kalman filter in R

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I have to calculate half life of an advertisement using Kalman filter in R. The paper 'Estimating the Half-life of Advertisements' ([Naik, 1999](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1008158119567)<sup>[1]</sup>) provides the base but am unable to understand how exactly the estimation is being done and since a lot of parameters that go in as the input to the kalman filters are unknown i am unable to move forward with my project.

Any suggestion as in how to go forward?

[1]: Naik, P.A. (1999),
"Estimating the Half-life of Advertisements,"
*Marketing Letters* 10:3, 351-362