# How to calculate advertising copy wearout using kalman filter?

Tags: r, kalman-filter, statistics-in-media

I have to calculate half life of an advertisement using Kalman filter in R. The paper 'Estimating the Half-life of Advertisements' (Naik, 1999[1]) provides the base but am unable to understand how exactly the estimation is being done and since a lot of parameters that go in as the input to the kalman filters are unknown i am unable to move forward with my project.

Any suggestion as in how to go forward?

[1]: Naik, P.A. (1999),
"Estimating the Half-life of Advertisements,"
Marketing Letters 10:3, 351-362

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? I seem to recall editing an essentially identical question only a day or so back.

Comment: Here it is -- [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95468/how-to-calculate-advertising-copy-wearout-using-kalman-filter-in-r). If you really want to ask that question but without the "in R" in the title you should edit your question, not repost it.